# Closing Animation Timeline Wp8

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8, timeline

I've used the phone Application analysis tool in visual studio to make a memory analysis on my app. In this I can see that some animation Timelines are created, even though I've commented out all the storyboards, so I was wondering if it is possible to delete or remove these animation timelines and if so how?